# Travis deploy library in Bintray. Build folder does not exist

Tags: java, build, kotlin, travis-ci, bintray

I try to upload my library on Bintray after a build with Travis-ci. I followed [this tutorial](https://techdev.io/en/developer-blog/how-to-publish-a-kotlin-library-to-bintray-using-gradle-and-travis-ci) and read [the documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/bintray).

But during the deployment phase I get the warning: 
`[Bintray Upload] Warning: Path: build/libs/ does not exist.`

My library is not deployed and I don't understand why travis can't find `build/libs`.
I checked with simple `ls` command in .travis.yml and the path is valid.

I am looking to send `.pom` and `.jar` files located in `build/libs` folder.
I use this path like this:

```
  "files":
  [
    {
      "includePattern": "build/libs/(.*)",
      "uploadPattern": "com/baillyj/jikankt/1.0.0/$1"
    }
  ]
```

Is the syntax not good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Travis stash any changes to the directory before deploying. Therefore `build/libs` was created in build step and deleted in deploy step. 
I add in `.travis.yml`:

```
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
```

I thank BanzaiMan who gave me the answer on github.